# Display Table Name in Query Results; SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm trying generate a column based on the title of a table.

Is there a way to display the table name specified in the FROM clause in the query results?

Thanks

Comment: What exactly u want?

Comment: Select  *,'table' [Source table] From  table

Comment: Hi Jithin. Thanks for the reply, I want to display the name of the table dynamically without having to hard code it. The context is that I have a set of tables where the year is in the table name but not contained anywhere in the data(!) so I'm trying to display the year in the table itself. The existing solution is to hard code the year but I was hoping to find a way of generating it as the exercise will be repeated at several points in the year and in subsequent years.

Comment: are you using dynamic sql? that might be the best option. If not, surely the tables in from clause are going to change in line with the table name in the future? are you simply looking to only have to change the from clause and the column name will stay in line with it?

Comment: Can you put some more info please. Please give us an example of the table name and the output you expect. As far as I know, there is no such inbuilt feature in SQL Server/ANSI-SQL. You may have to generate your Select statement dynamically. But again, people will be able to answer better with a little more info from your side.

Comment: Example: LOAD_UNISTATS_2013_ACCREDITATION

Comment: Required output: Value1, Value2, Value 3, Year

Comment: With year being a substring of the table name

Comment: "I want to display the name of the table dynamically without having to hard code it." - whatever you're using to populate the **table name** in your query text; also use that to populate the **static text for the last column** in @JithinShaji's suggestion...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments, it seems that you have multiple tables all with the same structure and similar names  This is almost always a sign of poor database design.  You should have a single table `LOAD_UNISTATS_ACCREDITATION` with a column for the year.

If you cannot change the database structure, then perhaps you can create a view:

```
create view v_LOAD_UNISTATS_ACCREDITATION as
    select lua.*, 2013 as year
    from LOAD_UNISTATS_2013_ACCREDITATION lua
    union all
    select lua.*, 2012 as year
    from LOAD_UNISTATS_2012_ACCREDITATION lua
    . . .;
```

But the answer to your question is "no".  There is no automated way to specify a table name in query.  And, for a simple reason.  The columns in a query are defined in the `SELECT` but tables are defined in the `FROM`.  A query can have multiple tables.  One could imagine a function such as `OBJECT_ID` for this purpose, but columns are not first class objects in the database.

Comment: Thanks all and indeed you're right Gordon. I'm afraid it's a set of tables that are produced for a year in isolation but we're trying to set them up for year on year comparison as a single entity as you describe. Thanks for taking the time to reply - that gives me some options to experiment with.

Answer (score 0):

The dynamic sql approach, where you could pass in a parameter with the table name (assuming it always has the same structure, length) would be something like this:

**Create Script:**

```
create table LOAD_UNISTATS_2013_ACCREDITATION (value1 int, value2 int)

insert into LOAD_UNISTATS_2013_ACCREDITATION (value1, value2)
values (1,2)
```

**Dynamic SQL:**

```
declare @sql nvarchar(200)
declare @tblname nvarchar(50)

set @tblname = 'LOAD_UNISTATS_2013_ACCREDITATION'
set @sql = 'SELECT value1,value2,' + substring(@tblname, 15, 4) 
           + ' as TableName FROM ' + @tblname
execute(@sql)
```

### [Demo Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6ab37/12)

Answer (score 0):

This query..

```
select
    st.text
from sys.dm_exec_requests as r
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(r.sql_handle) AS st
where r.session_id = @@SPID;
```

..will give you the raw text of the currently-executing SQL batch.  If it's a simple, single-query batch with no joins, or you follow a rigorous naming convention, it should be relatively easy to parse the table name out of `st.text`.  You will have to find a way of including the above into your actual query or batch without subverting its logic.

This is the very essence Cowboy Coding, however.  It will be difficult to get right, understand and change.  It does, however, answer the question posed.  @Gordon Linoff's solution of layering a view over the year-specific tables is the way to go for any professional deployment.  The process which creates a new table each year can also re-create the view to include the new table.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your query always has a single table in the FROM clause. If that is the case, I hope the below code will be helpful:

```
DECLARE @schema sysname = 'dbo';
DECLARE @tbl sysname = 'tbl_xyz';
DECLARE @Sql nvarchar(Max) = ''
DECLARE @Collist nvarchar(max) = ''


SELECT @Collist = @Collist + c.name + char(10) + ','
FROM sys.columns c
    JOIN sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id
    JOIN sys.schemas s ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
WHERE t.name = @tbl AND s.name = @schema

IF LEN(@Collist) = 0 PRINT 'Table not found'
ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @Sql = 'SELECT ' + char(10) + @Collist + '''' + @schema + '.' + @tbl + '''' + ' as TableName' +char(10)
            + 'FROM ' + @schema + '.' + @tbl


        PRINT @Sql
    END

EXECUTE sp_ExecuteSql @Sql
```